# recursion without explicitly setting variable javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here are two working versions (for Node.js) of the same recursive function.

**Version 1**

```
function getDependencies(mod, result) {
  result = result || []
  var dependencies = mod.dependencies || []
  Object.keys(dependencies).forEach(function(dep) {
    var key = dep + '@' + mod.dependencies[dep].version
    if (result.indexOf(key) === -1) result.push(key)
    getDependencies(mod.dependencies[dep], result) // COMPARE THIS LINE
  })
  return result.sort()
}
```

**Version 2**

```
function getDependencies(mod, result) {
  result = result || []
  var dependencies = mod.dependencies || []
  Object.keys(dependencies).forEach(function(dep) {
    var key = dep + '@' + mod.dependencies[dep].version
    if (result.indexOf(key) === -1) result.push(key)
    result = getDependencies(mod.dependencies[dep], result) // COMPARE THIS LINE
  })
  return result.sort()
}
```

How does version 1 of the function work, as compared to version 2, without explicitly setting the result variable?

Comment: Is your semi-colon key broken?

Comment: This is a Node.js solution from Nodeschool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.push(key)` and `result.sort()` both modify the `result` array that was passed in as an argument. So there's no need to assign it again in the caller.

Comment: So is it changed because of pass by reference? If getDepenencies() is recursively called multiple times, I do not understand how the results "add up" and are finally returned as one value.

Comment: When you pass or assign an object or array, you get a reference to the same object/array, it doesn't make a copy. So all the recursive calls are operating on the same `result` array.

Comment: @user3477405 - there's only one array.  When you pass it to a function, no copy is made - it's the same array.  So, if a function modifies it, the original is modified. No need to return it.  It isn't technically pass by reference, more like pass by pointer.